# Java FX 8 using Platform.runLater() in Application init() method to display Alert / Login boxes

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Please bear with me as this is going to be a pretty detailed and specific requirement. I also looked into numerous questions already listed on stackoverflow regarding Platform.runLater() usage. But I couldn't find an appropriate response. If someone can identify the correct question and mark this as a duplicate I would be great full all the same. Also I'm a newbie to JavaFX programming, so if I need to modify the architecture, please let me know.

I'm creating a stand-alone JavaFX application to run some unit tests based on user-defined requirements. Before running the actual tests, I need to make sure that the end-user is using the test with latest libraries available, by comparing the manifest files from remote Artifactory repo and the manifest files from jars on the current classpath. I want to store the credentials for Artifactory so that I can reuse them for subsequent executions. If the build numbers from remote and local manifest doesn't match, then I want to display an Error Alert window informing the user. I want to use a pre-loader to display a gif and appropriate messages in each of these steps.

```
public class UI extends Application 
{
    String username=null, password=null;
    Manifest remoteManifest, localManifest;

    @Override
    public void init() {

        notifyPreloader("Loading Stored Credentials");
        loadStoredCredentials();

        if(username == null && password == null) {
            notifyPreloader("Requesting New Credentials");
            getNewCredentials();
        }

        notifyPreloader("Reading remote manifest");
        readRemoteManifest();

        notifyPreloader("Reading local manifest");
        readLocalManifest();

        notifyPreloader("Comparing manifests");
        compareManifests();

    }

    private void getNewCredentials() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Login window for new credentials
                //Save credentials
            }
        });
    }

    private void readRemoteManifest() {
        // REST API call to read remote manifest
        if(HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) { // Stored credentials might have been read the first time which are expired, so try again.
            getNewCredentials();
            readRemoteManifest();
        } else {
            // update remote manifest object
        }
    }

    private void readLocalManifest() {
        // Update local manifest object
    }

    private void showAlert() {
        Platform.runLater( new Runnable() {
            // Display Alert window
        });
    }

    private void compareManifests() {
        if(remoteManifest == null) {
            showAlert();
        }

        if(localAlert == null) {
            showAlert();
        }

        if(remoteBuildNumber != localBuildNumber) {
            showAlert();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        //UI to select options and run tests
    }
}
```

I have three issues with this approach.

1. If I don't user Platform.runLater() for Alert Windows and Login Windows, then I get an error saying **Not on FX application thread; currentThread = JavaFX Application Thread error?**
2. If I use Platform.runLater() then even though the login window is active, the remaining alert windows also show up immediately without waiting to read the login credentials.
3. If I manually create the file to store current credentials, then any alert window that I have shows up twice.

Let me know if you need any additional info.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT-1:

Someone gave me an answer to fix the first two issues. But now the answer is missing. If they can re-post the answer, it would be helpful for others.

The solution was to move the Platform.runLater() code to compareManifests() method from showAlert() method. Instead I moved the Platform.runLater() to init() method. Now I only have one call to runLater().

The modified code to fix the first two issues.

```
public class UI extends Application 
{
    String username=null, password=null;
    Manifest remoteManifest, localManifest;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        Platform.runLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                notifyPreloader("Loading Stored Credentials");
                loadStoredCredentials();

                if(username == null && password == null) {
                    notifyPreloader("Requesting New Credentials");
                    getNewCredentials();
                }

                notifyPreloader("Reading remote manifest");
                readRemoteManifest();

                notifyPreloader("Reading local manifest");
                readLocalManifest();

                notifyPreloader("Comparing manifests");
                compareManifests();
            }
        });
    }

    private void getNewCredentials() {
        // Login window for new credentials
        //Save credentials
    }

    private void readRemoteManifest() {
        // REST API call to read remote manifest
        if(HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) { // Stored credentials might have been read the first time which are expired, so try again.
            getNewCredentials();
            readRemoteManifest();
        } else {
            // update remote manifest object
        }
    }

    private void readLocalManifest() {
        // Update local manifest object
    }

    private void showAlert() {
        // Display Alert window
    }

    private void compareManifests() {

        if(remoteManifest == null) {
            showAlert();
        }

        if(localAlert == null) {
            showAlert();
        }

        if(remoteBuildNumber != localBuildNumber) {
            showAlert();
        }
    }

    private void loadStoredCredentials() {
        // Read the credentials from a local file
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        //UI to select options and run tests
    }
}
```

Issue 3 is still occurring, there are two login windows being displayed now.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried performing the work in the start method? public final void start(final Stage primaryStage) {......  I have apps that launch Dialogues before the main GUI window, and that works fine.  It may be that the start() method is the first method that runs on the new (FxMain) Thread and that init() is for state initialisation?

Comment: As per [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) (the threading paragraph), the `init` method is called from the launcher thread, not the JavaFX one, that's why you get the first error. 
As @DrPhill suggests it, make the manifest version verification as part of your tests. Consider it as the first step of your tests, but wait for your appication initialization. Use the `start` method.

Comment: in short: runLater put into FX thread queue and the next line is executed imminently. so if you want block operation you have to call the next line inside the runLater or with a flag(I don't know if launcher has to finish in order of FX to start). do note that if you with UI thread you should not do sleep or infante loop.

Comment: (you may want to see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html)

Comment: didn't really dig into your requirements so don't know if it's useful, but here's a link that helped me a while ago:  https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/09/javafx-how-to-easily-implement-application-preloader-2/